# No buttons display in linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made another linear layout with buttons just fine, but this just doesn't seem to work...I've tried changing the widths, heights, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_a"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/choice_b"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because you have a fixed height of 45 dp to your main linear layout and your first button is match parent so you will not see more than 1 button

Comment: instead of `match_parent` in textView use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No buttons display in linear layout?

because your `textview` has **`match_parent`** height just change the height of your `textview` to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`** it will work

Also change the hiehit of your root **`LinearLayout`** to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`**

SAMPLE CODE

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_a"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_b"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the basics of Height and Width

As you have set

> android:layout_height="45dip"

It should be **match_parent** or **wrap_content** Practically.

Then your TextView Height is `"match_parent"`

Change it to `"wrap_content"`

All these before please understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code i have find some minor problem:

1. linear layout height is static (45)
2. textview  height is match_parent

change:

1. set parent layout (Linear layout) match parent or wrap_content
2. set text view height set wrap_content.

**see layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/choice_a"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/choice_b"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

please make some layout changes as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice_a"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/choice_b"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```